# parenthetical... suggestion?

Tags: grammar

okay, trying to settle an argument. on my dating profile, one of the prompts says: "together we could.."

among other things, my response includes, "eat (spicy) food".
my friends argue that this statement says "we could eat spicy food". what i meant was, we could eat food, spicy optional. did i screw this up? one of these friends has severe dyslexia and is functionally illiterate. i love her very much, but don't trust her opinion on the matter. i have scoured the internet and couldn't find any validation... nor was i able to find another example of this type of parenthetical usage.

i need your help !
but please be gentle - i am a frequent visitor of this site but a very infrequent poster.

Comment: Personally, I might have worded it as "eat spicy (or not) food". To me, this better implies that "spicy" is the your default preference, but not mandatory.

Comment: I understood it as you intended It is 2 suggestions: food, and spicy food.... I suggest you would enjoy a date more with someone who understands you.

Comment: You could start with proper punctuation, capital letters at the start of complete sentences, and such.

Comment: Might I suggest, as an extremely minor revision that hopefully eliminates the vagueness involved, "eat (spicy?) food". This is a variant that I see very frequently in writing when there is some uncertainty about an optional suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand the parenthesis means that what is inside it is optional. So your sentence could be paraphrased as: "Together we could eat food, and if you feel like it that food can be spicy".

But since you specifically offer only spicy as an option (and not other types of food, e.g. sweet or sour), that option obtains a lot more weight and importance in relation to the other options, including the neutral one ("eat plain food"). And since the sentence turns strange and bewildering without that adjective – no one says "we could eat food"! –, you do in fact make it almost impossible to read the sentence without it.

So, in my opinion, you are both right! You, syntactically, and your friend, semantically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that sounds right. While reading this, I could tell you meant spicy as optional, but maybe you could try putting, "We could eat food, sweet or spicy," or something like that. The other thing I think you could do is put something like, "We could eat food together(I prefer spicy)," to tell them what you mean.